# Choosing line type and color in Gnuplot 4.0

Tags: gnuplot

I have two pairs of datasets, which I need to plot using Gnuplot.

I want the first pair to be plotted in red, one solid and one dashed. The second pair, I want to plot in blue, one solid and one dashed.

I've experimented with `set style line` several times, but I cannot get this exact behaviour. My last attempt (attached) plots the first pair in red (solid) and the second pair in blue (dotted).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
set style line 1 lt 1 lw 3 pt 3
set style line 2 lt 1 lw 3 pt 3
set style line 3 lt 3 lw 3 pt 3
set style line 4 lt 3 lw 3 pt 3
plot 'data1.dat' using 1:3 w l ls 1,\
     'data1.dat' using 1:4 w l ls 2,\
     'data2.dat' using 1:3 w l ls 3,\
     'data2.dat' using 1:4 w l ls 4
```

Answer (score 29):

You need to use *linecolor* instead of lc, like:

`set style line 1 lt 1 lw 3 pt 3 linecolor rgb "red"`

"help set style line" gives you more info.

Comment: He is asking about Gnuplot 4.0, which doesn't have 'rgb "red"' syntax

Answer (score 14):

I've ran into this topic, because i was struggling with dashed lines too **(gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0)**

If you use:

```
set termoption dashed
```

**Your posted code will work** accordingly.

*Related question:*
However, if I want to export a png with:
set terminal png, this isn't working anymore. Anyone got a clue why?

Turns out, out, gnuplots png export library doesnt support this.
Possbile solutions:

- one can simply export to ps, then convert it with pstopng
- according to @christoph, if you use `pngcairo` as your terminal (`set terminal pngcairo`) it will work

Comment: After some research turns out, gnuplots png export library doesnt support this.
However one can simply export to ps, then convert it with pstopng.

Comment: The `png` terminal (uses `libgd`) doesn't, but the `pngcairo` terminal supports dashed lines.

Answer (score 7):

You can also set the 'dashed' option when setting your terminal, for instance:

```
set term pdf dashed
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the syntax:

```
  set terminal pdf {monochrome|color|colour}
                   {{no}enhanced}
                   {fname "<font>"} {fsize <fontsize>}
                   {font "<fontname>{,<fontsize>}"}
                   {linewidth <lw>} {rounded|butt}
                   {solid|dashed} {dl <dashlength>}}
                   {size <XX>{unit},<YY>{unit}}
```

and an example:

```
set terminal pdfcairo monochrome enhanced font "Times-New-Roman,12" dashed
```

Answer (score 6):

You might want to look at the Pyxplot plotting package http://pyxplot.org.uk which has very similar syntax to gnuplot, but with the rough edges cleaned up. It handles colors and line styles quite neatly, and homogeneously between x11 and eps/pdf terminals.

The Pyxplot script for what you want to do above would be:

```
set style 1 lt 1 lw 3 color red
set style 2 lt 1 lw 3 color blue
set style 3 lt 2 lw 3 color red
set style 4 lt 2 lw 3 color blue
plot 'data1.dat' using 1:3 w l style 1,\
  'data1.dat' using 1:4 w l style 2,\
  'data2.dat' using 1:3 w l style 3,\
  'data2.dat' using 1:4 w l style 4`
```

Answer (score 4):

Edit: Sorry, this won't work for you. I just remembered the line color thing is in 4.2. I ran into this problem in the past and my fix was to upgrade gnuplot.

You can control the color with set style line as well. "lt 3" will give you a dashed line while "lt 1" will give you a solid line. To add color, you can use "lc rgb 'color'". This should do what you need:

```
set style line 1 lt 1 lw 3 pt 3 lc rgb "red"
set style line 2 lt 3 lw 3 pt 3 lc rgb "red"
set style line 3 lt 1 lw 3 pt 3 lc rgb "blue"
set style line 4 lt 3 lw 3 pt 3 lc rgb "blue"
```

Comment: unfortunately lc is not available in Gnuplot 4.0

Comment: As far as I know you simply cannot specify linetypes with the x11 term. I'm using gnuplot 4.4 and I've *never* succeeded dashing a line, regardless of options (and certainly trying linetype)..

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is old but I found this very helpful http://www.gnuplot.info/demo_canvas/dashcolor.html . So you can choose linetype and linecolor separately but you have to precede everything by "set termoption dash" (worked for me in gnuplot 4.4).

Comment: link moved: http://skuld.bmsc.washington.edu/~merritt/gnuplot/demo_canvas/dashcolor.html

Comment: link expired again... This should work longer: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.6/dashcolor.html