# How can I set the line color when plotting with Ruby's GnuPlot (rgplot)?

Tags: ruby, gnuplot

The default line color is some sickly yellow and I want to change it to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, assuming your data set variables (x, y, z) are already defined

```
::Gnuplot.open do |gp|
  ::Gnuplot::Plot.new(gp) do |plot|
    plot.data << ::Gnuplot::DataSet.new([x, y, z]) do |ds|
      ds.with = 'errorb lt rgb "black"'
    end
  end
end
```

The line specifying the colour is also specifying that you want to plot with error bars (for the z variable). It can also be formatted like:

```
ds.with = "errorb lt rgb \"black\""
```

And of course you can remove the 'errorb' and just plot a two-variable (x,y) dataset.

Incidentally, to see which colours are available, type

```
show colournames
```

in your terminal inside a gnuplot environment. Try http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.6/gnuplot.pdf for more documentation.

Comment: Right, I ended up with: `ds.with  = "lines lt rgb \"black\""`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have GnuPlot 4.x is that right? Because as far as I can remember the color option doesn't work in previous versions (correct me please if I am wrong).

Well now for your answer. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075283/choosing-line-type-and-color-in-gnuplot-4-0) out to see the syntax in order to set the color of the line (you need the `linecolor rgb "red"` portion I believe). Now you can pass a `set` command from the Ruby wrapper to GnuPlot like this:

```
Gnuplot.open do |gp|
   Gnuplot::Plot.new(gp) do |plot|
      plot.set("style", "line 1 lt 1 lw 3 pt 3 linecolor rgb \"red\"")
   end
end
```

To see for yourself (and I believe it should help you out by browsing the code) the code is on [github](https://github.com/rdp/ruby_gnuplot/blob/master/lib/gnuplot.rb#L148). I hope I helped you.

Comment: This looks like it should work, but it doesn't (no errs or messages). This is my plot code: http://pastie.org/4203594. It would be great if this "style" setting could be set at the level for each Gnuplot::DataSet.

Comment: I think it can get set for each dataset..See that `line 1`? I believe that it is for the individual dataset. Instead of `linecolor` use `lc` and see if that works. Also what's your gnuplot version?

Comment: I tested with line 1 through 5 - same missing result :oP. There is no `set` method for the the `ds` object in my code example. According to the gnuplot help system `lc` and `linecolor` are synonyms. My Gnuplot version is 4.6.0. rgplot is 2.4.1.

Comment: Try to write the `linecolor` statement inside the `plot.style    "fill solid 0.5 border"` definition and see if that works. Otherwise I don't know why it is not working :/

Answer (score 0):

With gnuplot 5.2 and the gem [gnuplot 2.6.2](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/gnuplot/2.6.2/) (because I can no longer find the gem [rgplot](https://rubygems.org/search?query=rgplot)):

```
Gnuplot.open do |gp|
  Gnuplot::Plot.new(gp) do |plot|
    plot.data << ::Gnuplot::DataSet.new([x, y, z]) do |ds|
      ds.linecolor = 'rgb "blue"'
      ds.linecolor = 'rgb "#0000FF"' # another way
    end
  end
end
```