# Setting line type in GnuplotPy?

Tags: python, visualization, gnuplot, data-visualization

In Gnuplot, the `linetype` or `lt` flag allows the user to select the [line type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075283/choosing-line-type-and-color-in-gnuplot-4-0) (dashed, dotted, solid, etc).

I'm using a Python wrapper called [Gnuplot-Py](http://gnuplot-py.sourceforge.net/). Here's an example:

```
import Gnuplot
data1 = [[3, 0.03], [4, 0.02], [5, 0.017]]
data2 = [[3, 0.027], [4, 0.015], [5, 0.014]]

gp = Gnuplot.Gnuplot(persist = 1)
gp('set terminal x11 size 350,225') 
gp('set pointsize 2')
gp('set yrange [0.0:0.05]')
plot1 = Gnuplot.PlotItems.Data(data1, with_="linespoints lt rgb 'black' lw 6 pt 1", title="data1")
plot2 = Gnuplot.PlotItems.Data(data2, with_="linespoints lt rgb 'blue' lw 6 pt 8", title="data2")
gp.plot(plot2, plot1)

epsFilename='testLines.eps'
gp.hardcopy(epsFilename, terminal = 'postscript', enhanced=1, color=1) #must come after plot() function
gp.reset()
```

Here's the output:
[image]

---

As you can see in the above code, `lt` (linetype) is in the `Gnuplot.PlotItems.Data(..., with_=...)` commands. In plain Gnuplot, we would just do `lt 1` to choose line type 1. However, Gnuplot-Py seems to arbitrarily choose the line type (notice that one line is solid, and one line is dashed in the above plot). Let's try a couple of strategies for manually changing the line type in Gnuplot-Py...

**Strategy 1.** I tried `lt 1` instead of `lt` in the `with_` string. This throws an error, but it still produces the same plot as we saw above.

```
plot1 = Gnuplot.PlotItems.Data(data1, with_="linespoints lt 1 rgb 'black' lw 6 pt 1", title="data1") #returns the error `line 0: ';' expected
```

**Strategy 2.** I also tried removing `lt` from the `with_` string. This throws an error and ignores the formatting for the `data1` line (see green line for `data1` below).

```
plot1 = Gnuplot.PlotItems.Data(data1, with_="linespoints rgb 'black' lw 6 pt 1", title="data1") #returns the error `line 0: ';' expected
```

[image]

**Strategy 3.** If I add `gp('set style lt 1')`, I again get the error `line 0: expecting 'data', 'function', 'line', 'fill' or 'arrow'`, and the plot is unchanged from the original shown above.

---

### **How can I manually select the linetype in GnuplotPy?**

Comment: With strategy 3, it should be `gp('set style line 1 lc rgb "blue"')` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
with_="linespoints lt 1 lw 6 pt 1 linecolor rgb 'black'" #put this inside Gnuplot.PlotItems.Data() command
```

In my original post, I was doing `with_="linespoints lt rgb 'black' ..."`. In other words, I was jumbling the `linespoints` and `linecolor` arguments together. I'm not sure why this didn't crash even when I didn't specify a `linetype`.

Anyway, the takeaway is that we need this type of setup for the `with_` string: 
`linespoints (args to linespoints) linecolor (args to linecolor)`

Here's the result:
[image]