# Different line styles for vectors from the same data file

Tags: gnuplot

Here is my data file:

```
25 10 8
0  50 11
34 25 0
14 0 22
200 25 56
```

And I plot 3D vectors with `splot`:

```
splot "data" using (0):(0):(0):1:2:3 with vectors
```

[image]

But I would like different colors for my vectors, using something like `ls nth_vector` with `splot` (so `ls 1` for the first line of the file, then `ls 2`, etc.). Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the answers to this question of any help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075283

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you double space your data file you can achieve this using `index`. You can use `awk` within `gnuplot` to do the spacing on the fly:

```
splot for [i=0:system("wc -l < data")] '<awk -v s="\n" "{print s}1" data' using (0):(0):(0):1:2:3 index i notitle with vectors
```

The `system` command counts the number of lines in the file. `awk` prints two newlines for every line in the data file, so each line has a separate `index`. I have used a variable containing the `\n` character as this avoids difficulties in escaping strings.

#### edit

There's no need for any of that `awk`. You can use `stats` to get the number of lines in your file and `every` to plot each line separately:

```
stats 'data' nooutput
splot for [i=0:STATS_records] "data" using (0):(0):(0):1:2:3 every ::i::i with vectors notitle
```

[image: image showing plot]

Comment: @Nicolas I have modified my answer so that it doesn't depend on any other utilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the row number (zeroth column) as `linetype` index for the `linecolor variable` option:

```
splot 'data' using (0):(0):(0):1:2:3:0 with vectors lc var
```

For the `vectors` plotting style you could even use `arrowstyle variable` to change the whole arrow settings.